# Sort a json array, first by search text and remaining results alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a json array, which I need to short first based on some search text, and then alphabetically. so basically in below array if I search for **"beau"** everything starting with beau should be kept on top(sorted alphabetically), and the remaining results will be sorted also alphabetically(even if we have that search text somewhere in the middle of the text) and should start right after the ones

**Need solution in Javascript**

Array :

```
[
{
 "value": "1",
 "text": "BEAUMONT Habitation 54"
},
{
 "value": "2",
 "text": "BEAUMONT Place de Renival"
},
{
 "value": "3",
 "text": "BEAUMONT Rue des Tiennes"
},
{
 "value": "4",
 "text": "BEAUMONT Rue Grand Chemin"
},
{
 "value": "5",
 "text": "BRUYERES Chênes"
},
{
 "value": "6",
 "text": "CEROUX Cabine"
},
{
 "value": "7",
 "text": "CEROUX Chapelle aux Sabots"
},
{
 "value": "8",
 "text": "CEROUX Place Communale"
},
{
 "value": "9",
 "text": "CEROUX Quatre Bras"
},
{
 "value": "10",
 "text": "Station Jambeaux"
},
{
 "value": "11",
 "text": "Reseau Street"
},
{
 "value": "12",
 "text": "beaux street"
}
]
```

**EDIT**

This is fine, but in another case where I have this data transformed in something like this, this sort is not working

```
   {
      "item":{
         "value":"1558",
         "text":"BEAUMONT Habitation 54"
      },
      "refIndex":0,
      "matches":[
         {
            "indices":[
               [
                  0,
                  1
               ]
            ],
            "value":"BEAUMONT Habitation 54",
            "key":"text"
         }
      ],
      "score":0.018533147937493524
   },
   {
      "item":{
         "value":"1560",
         "text":"BEAUMONT Place de Renival"
      },
      "refIndex":3,
      "matches":[
         {
            "indices":[
               [
                  0,
                  1
               ]
            ],
            "value":"BEAUMONT Place de Renival",
            "key":"text"
         }
      ],
      "score":0.03162277660168379
   }
]
```

to make it work I made some changes to the code, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
function sortByInput(data, input = null) {
  if (!input) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => a.item.text.localeCompare(b.item.text));
  }
  
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(^${input})`, "i");
    const aMatch = regex.test(a.item.text);
    const bMatch = regex.test(b.item.text);

    if (aMatch || bMatch) return -aMatch + bMatch;

    return a.item.text.localeCompare(b.item.text);
  });
}
```

Comment: You have two different sets of data, one is an array of objects containing only `value` and `text` and another is an array of objects with various other attributes and `item` that contains `value` and `text`. Which set of data should we try and sort?

Comment: Hi Dane, I need to sort the array based on the value of "text" alphabetically. For example, a index which has a item with text starting with "a" should be at a higher index(0) than "b" (1) and so on.

Comment: In the edit, you refer to a.text instead of a.item.text

Comment: that was a typo, changed, still it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic solution is to use the default Javascript [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and pass your own compare function.

---

In the example below I check if there is any `input` and depending on that I sort just alphabetically, or I sort by `input`(by checking with the Regular Expression if the element starts with `input`) and then sort alphabetically.

```js
const data = [
  { value: "1", text: "BEAUMONT Habitation 54" },
  { value: "2", text: "BEAUMONT Place de Renival" },
  { value: "3", text: "BEAUMONT Rue des Tiennes" },
  { value: "4", text: "BEAUMONT Rue Grand Chemin" },
  { value: "5", text: "BRUYERES Chênes" },
  { value: "6", text: "CEROUX Cabine" },
  { value: "7", text: "CEROUX Chapelle aux Sabots" },
  { value: "8", text: "CEROUX Place Communale" },
  { value: "9", text: "CEROUX Quatre Bras" },
  { value: "10", text: "Station Jambeaux" },
  { value: "11", text: "Reseau Street" },
  { value: "12", text: "beaux street" }
];



function sortByInput(data, input = null) {
  if (!input) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text));
  }
  
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(^${input})`, "i");
    const aMatch = regex.test(a.text);
    const bMatch = regex.test(b.text);

    if (aMatch || bMatch) return -aMatch + bMatch;

    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
  });
}

console.log(sortByInput([...data], "ceroux"));
```

---

## Edit:

here is an updated version
with a third parameter `compareValue` which specifies the value that it sorts by (I made it default to `"item.text"` which matches your example)

I also added the function `getProp` to dynamically get the props of data with the String `compareValue`

```js
function sortByInput(data, input = null, compareValue = "item.text") {
    const getProp = (object, path) =>
        path.split(".").reduce((o, p) => o[p], object);

    if (!input) {
        return data.sort((a, b) =>
            getProp(a, compareValue).localeCompare(getProp(b, compareValue))
        );
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`(^${input})`, "i");
        const aMatch = regex.test(getProp(a, compareValue));
        const bMatch = regex.test(getProp(b, compareValue));

        if (aMatch || bMatch) return -aMatch + bMatch;

        return getProp(a, compareValue).localeCompare(getProp(b, compareValue));
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Johannes, thanks for the answer, this seems fine, but i have another case where this is not working, Please check the edit.

Comment: I had gone long way, but this seems more optimized way to do it and works, thanks